# Make a cygwin script shortcut that ask for parameters

Tags: bash, cygwin, shell-script

I created a script for cygwin and set a shortcut as explained in the end of [this tutorial](http://www.trueblade.com/knowledge/using-rsync-and-cygwin-to-sync-files-from-a-linux-server-to-a-windows-notebook-pc).

Altough, my script has to receive variable parameters and the way it was set either it runs as if no parameters were passed or if I set anything after the script path it considers it as literal parameter.

Consider a script (echo.sh) like this:

```
#!/bin/bash    
echo "this"$1
sleep 30
```

The target in my shortcut:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -i '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/echo.sh'
```

When I click in the shortcut it already prints 'this' and sleeps.
I tried:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -i '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/echo.sh $1' #file not found
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -i '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/echo.sh' $1 #prints 'this$1'
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you tried ?

Comment: Shortcuts cannot use variable parameters. You should modify your script to ask for the values to use or read them from a file as appropriate. Note it is actually very unclear what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I've added details...so do I really need to change the script?

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments, shortcuts cannot handle variables.

You can create a batch script (`script.cmd`), that receives an argument and invokes Cygwin.

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe /usr/bin/bash --login "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/echo.sh" %1
```

You can also drag and drop an icon to your `script.cmd`, and it receives the path of the dropped file as an argument. You have to take care of Windows <-> Cygwin path translations (`cygpath`) however.